# HTTP Post deadlock

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this code

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(string url, HttpRequestMessage requestBody)
        {
            var ts = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            var signature = CreateSignature(ts, HttpMethod.Post, url, RequestBodyToBytes(requestBody));

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(SUMSUB_TEST_BASE_URL)
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-App-Token", SUMSUB_APP_TOKEN);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-App-Access-Sig", signature);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-App-Access-Ts", ts.ToString());

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestBody.Content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
            }
            return response;
        }
```

When I run it in a console app, nothing is wrong and perfectly running.  But when I run it on xamarin forms its encountering a deadlock.

once this line "var response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestBody.Content);" is excuted, it will deadlock.

Any insights?

Comment: probably, server keeps your socket open which may caused enabled infinite re tries .and i can say it's SSL problem because if SSL stage was completed successfully, the  server would response to your request whether timeout or other internal errors .

Comment: But when I run this code through a console, it runs flawlessly.

Comment: check if you get connected to server while testing in xamarin env?

Comment: yes, it is connected

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but adding Cofigureawait(false) seems to do the trrick.

Comment: If you do that,  you will lose a possible exception and the response will not be set in time.